# SharePoint Document library alerts not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019, sharepoint-alerts

I have migrated from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019, here I am facing a strange issue, like list alerts are working fine but when I create any alert on any document library, no mails are triggering(means alerts are not working on document library), neither the old alerts that were created in SharePoint 2013 are working in new environment. please suggest what to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by re-registering the alerts, for reference please see point no. 9 in the below link:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/sharepoint-alerts-not-working-troubleshooting-checklist.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Please check as following:

1. Will the same user be alerted in list or library?
2. When you set an alert on a specific file instead of the entire library, is it effective?
3. Does the alert setting only have no effect in the migration library?

Please create a new library in new server, send alerts on single file or entire library to multiple users to compare the results.

Comment: 1. No, many more than me
2. No
3. In the migration environment, it is happening with each library, I have around 46 sites in my current environment. Also, FYI only document library is causing the issue, Lists are working fine

Comment: Have you created a new library after migrating? Run psconfig to check if it could repair document alert issues.